# What is the difference in functionality between the table sorter pager widget and pager plugin?

Tags: ajax, pagination, tablesorter

Does the pager widget do more than the pager plugin? Is one going to be chosen for the future and the other one deprecated?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tablesorter was built to be extensible by using widgets. The pager plugin, is just that, a plugin and because of that the plugin is initialized after tablesorter has completed setup with all widgets applied. This makes it slightly more difficult to make the two systems interact.

Currently, the functionality of the pager plugin & pager widget (still in beta) are essentially the same. The main differences are the way they are initialized and the naming of the options.

Eventually, when the next version (v3) comes out, all of tablesorter will be modular. Even sorting will become it's own widget, and the pager plugin will be phased out in favor of the pager widget. The download page will also allow you to select which themes, widgets & parsers to include in your build.